# $emit to immediate parent controller only

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to $emit to immediate parent controller?

I have different controllers, each controllers uses a child pagination directive that kinda looks like this.

```
.directive('pagination', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/Views/Shared/_Pagination.html',
    scope: { pagination: "=pagination" },
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.$watch('pagination.Page', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.$emit('pageChanged', { page: newVal });
        });
    }]
}
```

When you change a page for a controller, the pagination directive will send message for parent controller to catch, and the parent controller httpGet to get another page.

The problem is: if i have Controller A , which contains child controller B, which both uses pagination. And when a page changes on controller B, both controller B and A will catch the message since A is a parent of B. So, is there a way to send message to only the most immediate parent B only, given that I changed a page on controller B.

Or, if i am designing this wrong.. please give some input too. Thanks!

Comment: you can send extra param in the $emit and decide in both controllers where its belong

Comment: @NechemyaKanelsky can you give an example? What kind of parameter would i be sending? I don't want to be hardcoding this because this scenario will be used throughout the application. I want to make it to modular.

Comment: so you can make switch inside your directice controller based on all of your controllers and then use custom $emit for each controller. or do all of the redirects inside some main controller / sevice based on the current url and map it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## to answer your question

Inside your parent controller you can use

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

This will allow the current listener node to process the event, but any subsequent listeners will not receive it for processing.

> stopPropagation - {function=}: calling stopPropagation function will cancel further event propagation (available only for events that were $emit-ed).

## a better way

Since you're basically using a callback paradigm in which given a particular event, a directive will call a function passed to it, then you could use a callback expression on your directive's scope.

```
{
    scope: { pageChanged: '&' },
    link: function( $scope, elem, attrs ){
         //somewhere you trigger your pageChanged logic then fire this
         $scope.pageChanged({ $page: newVal })
    }
}
```

**where your directive is declared**

```
<div pagination page-changed="parentControllerFunc($page)">
```

This is more *angular-ish* than using `$emit` since you're basically trying to communicate betw. a directive and some view's controller in which the directive resides.  Using the angular `$emit/$broadcast` APIs is more for trying to communicate via an event bus where the constituents might know about or cannot communicate with each other more directly.